# Test facebook share link for password protected domains

Tags: facebook, apache, facebook-graph-api

I have site with password protection (When we access the site it will ask username and passwod). I want to test facebook share functionality.

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=www.example.com" target="_blank">Share</a>
```

When i try to click share link it will displying 404 Authentication Required. I want to share the link from my development environment.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook can´t bypass the password protection, so it sees the 404 error. That´s a feature, not a bug ;)

You can still share the link btw, it will just not see any Open Graph tags. You may try to add them to the 404 page.

You could also add a token to the link when you share it - if that token is there, present a page with the correct Open graph tags and redirect with JavaScript. Facebook will see the tags - the scraper ignores JavaScript. If the user visits the link, he will get redirected. Just a quick idea.